# Azure App Service "FailedToLocateDevelopmentCertificateFile" error with Docker image

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a docker image containing a .NET Core 3.1 Web API. It runs locally and unit tests on both the Docker image work in the devops pipeline. It appears to build and deploy with no errors however when I try to run it I get the following error. I can see it must be deployed correct as the 2nd line in the log below is logged by the `Program.cs` file (see further down). Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

Please bear with me, I am new to Azure and containers. If you need more information about the deployment let me know and I will update the question.

Thank you in advance.

**Error log:**

```
2020-03-27T13:43:38.706066600Z [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: MyApplication.Service.Program[0]
2020-03-27T13:43:38.706103500Z       MyApplication Service is starting.
2020-03-27T13:43:40.528762987Z {"@t":"2020-03-27T13:43:40.4726007Z","@mt":"Failed to locate the development https certificate at '{certificatePath}'.","@l":"Debug","certificatePath":null,"EventId":{"Id":2,"Name":"FailedToLocateDevelopmentCertificateFile"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer"}
2020-03-27T13:43:40.761834453Z [41m[1m[37mcrit[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
2020-03-27T13:43:40.761897653Z       Unable to start Kestrel.
2020-03-27T13:43:40.761904153Z System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied
2020-03-27T13:43:40.769929759Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.769948159Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.769953859Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770376759Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770387759Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770393259Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770398559Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770403259Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770407659Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770412059Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770685859Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.770966160Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933067575Z Unhandled exception. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933104075Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933110975Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933115675Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933120075Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933131775Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransportFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933136675Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933141875Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933146075Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933150375Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933154575Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933158875Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933163275Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933167575Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933171875Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933176075Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933182675Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.933186975Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
2020-03-27T13:43:40.959954394Z    at MyApplication.Service.Program.Main(String[] p_lstArgs) in /app/MyApplication.Service/Program.cs:line 18
2020-03-27T13:43:41.294359133Z /app/run.sh: line 2:     6 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet MyApplication.Service.dll
```

**Program.cs**

```
        public static void Main(string[] p_lstArgs)
        {
            var objHost = CreateHostBuilder(p_lstArgs).Build();
            var objLogger = objHost.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            objLogger.LogInformation("MyApplication Service is starting.");

            objHost.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] p_lstArgs) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(p_lstArgs)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(objWebBuilder =>
                {
                    objWebBuilder
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .ConfigureLogging((objHostingContext, objLoggingBuilder) =>
                        {
                            objLoggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights();
                            objLoggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
                        })
                        .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:80");
                });
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        private const string HEAL_CHECK_NAME = "ReadinessLiveness";

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment p_objEnvironment)
        {
            var objBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(p_objEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{p_objEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var objBuildConfig = objBuilder.Build();

            if (objBuildConfig["KEY_VAULT_URI"] is var strKeyVaultUri && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strKeyVaultUri))
                objBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(strKeyVaultUri);

            Configuration = objBuilder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection p_objServices)
        {
            p_objServices.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            // Configure AppInsights
            p_objServices.AddApplicationInsightsKubernetesEnricher();
            p_objServices.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            // Add health check
            p_objServices.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck(HEAL_CHECK_NAME, () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy("OK"));

            p_objServices.AddControllers();

            // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
            p_objServices.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApplication Service API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(
            IApplicationBuilder p_objApplicationBuilder,
            IWebHostEnvironment p_objWebHostEnvironment,
            ILoggerFactory p_objLoggerFactory,
            IHttpContextAccessor p_objHttpContextAccessor)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .WriteTo.Console(new CompactJsonFormatter())
              .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
              .CreateLogger();

            // Important: it has to be first: enable global logger
            p_objApplicationBuilder.UseGlobalLoggerHandler();

            // Important: it has to be second: Enable global exception, error handling
            p_objApplicationBuilder.UseGlobalExceptionHandler();

            // TODO: Add middleware AuthZ here

            p_objApplicationBuilder.UseRouting();
            p_objApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(objEndpoints =>
            {
                objEndpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");
                objEndpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            p_objApplicationBuilder.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            p_objApplicationBuilder.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApplication Service API V1");
            });
        }
```

**DockerFile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 as base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY NuGet.Config ./NuGet.Config
COPY MyApplication.Core/*.csproj ./MyApplication.Core/
COPY MyApplication.Service/*.csproj ./MyApplication.Service/
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet restore /app/MyApplication.Core/
RUN dotnet restore /app/MyApplication.Service/

WORKDIR /app
COPY MyApplication.Core/. ./MyApplication.Core/
COPY MyApplication.Service/. ./MyApplication.Service/

FROM build AS testrunner

WORKDIR /app/tests
COPY NuGet.Config ./NuGet.Config
COPY MyApplication.Service.Tests/*.csproj .
WORKDIR /app/tests
RUN dotnet restore /app/tests/

WORKDIR /app/tests
RUN mkdir -p TestResults/Coverage
COPY MyApplication.Service.Tests/. .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "--logger:trx"]

FROM build AS publish


WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish /app/MyApplication.Service/ -c release -o ./out --no-restore

FROM base AS runtime

LABEL Tags="Azure,AKS,Processor"

ARG user=apiuser

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -U $user

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out ./
COPY scripts/. ./
RUN \
    # Ensures the entry point is executable
    chmod ugo+x /app/run.sh

RUN chown -R $user.$user /app

# Set it for subsequent commands
USER $user

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app/run.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the first line was just a warning. The actually error stopping the container running was fixed by changing the UseUrls to 8080:

[image]